# MySQL: Load csv file to mysql

Tags: mysql, csv, load

I'm having problems when loading a csv file into **MySQL 5.7** with **MySQL Workbench**.

### Example Data

```
ESH13   1/2/2013    10:04:35    1451    1
ESH13   1/2/2013    10:04:35    1451.25 2
ESH13   1/2/2013    10:04:35    1451    1
ESH13   1/2/2013    10:04:35    1451    1
ESH13   1/2/2013    10:04:36    1451    1
ESH13   1/2/2013    10:04:36    1451    2
```

---

### **Originally I tried using this [below] method to start:**

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv"; 

CREATE TABLE es (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    ticker VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    date DATE NOT NULL,
    time DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) NULL,
    price DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) NULL,
    vol DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:\Users\YCM LLC\Desktop\HFT\ES_test.csv'
INTO TABLE es_test1
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**This error occurs when the above is run:**

- > Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the
  >   --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement.

I tried to modify `C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini` by blocking the statement as shown below, but I get an "*Access is denied*" when I try to save the changes.

```
# Secure File Priv.
# secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads"
```

---

**I then tried to use of "local" keyword in the LOAD DATA INFILE statement:**

```
    LOAD DATA local INFILE 'C:\Users\YCM LLC\Desktop\HFT\ES_test.csv'
    INTO TABLE es_test1
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
    ENCLOSED BY '"'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

**This error occurs when the above is run:**

> Error Code: 2. File 'C:UsersYCM LLCDesktopHFTES_test.csv' not found
>   (Errcode: 2 - No such file or directory)

---

I was able to get data to load after getting adjusting per the advice from [a] the person that answered my question in a comment, but I started having trouble loading time string data to a table

```
CREATE TABLE es (
    ticker VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    xdate DATE NOT NULL,
    time Time NULL,
    price DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) NULL,
    vol DECIMAL(10 , 2 ) NULL
   );

LOAD DATA local INFILE 'C:\\Users\\YCM LLC\\Desktop\\HFT\\ES_test.csv'
INTO TABLE es
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
(ticker, @var1, @var2, price, vol) 
SET xdate = STR_TO_DATE(@var1, '%m/%d/%Y'),
    time = STR_TO_DATE(@var2, '%hh:%mm:%ss');
```

**This error occurs when the above is run:**

> 6 row(s) affected, 6 warning(s): 1411 Incorrect datetime value:
>   '10:04:35' for function str_to_date 1411 Incorrect datetime value:
>   '10:04:35' for function str_to_date 1411 Incorrect datetime value:
>   '10:04:35' for function str_to_date 1411 Incorrect datetime value:
>   '10:04:35' for function

Comment: I can load the data using #2. I ran into another problem. I cant load the time into mysql. Please see the second part of the above question. Tks

Comment: Yes, the date and time is on separate columns. I have amended the suggestion on the second half of the question. Is it possible to load everything using MySQL instead of using PowerShell? The error message is                                                                                                 
 6 row(s) affected, 6 warning(s): 1411 Incorrect datetime value: '10:04:35' for function str_to_date 1411 Incorrect datetime value: '10:04:35' for function str_to_date 1411 Incorrect datetime value: '10:04:35' for function str_to_date 1411 Incorrect datetime value: '10:04:35' for function ...

Comment: Its has loaded successfully now for a small sample. But seem to take forever for a full set. Since the first column is fixed name, possible to avoid loading the first column into MySQL table so that it will be faster? Is it possible to partition the loading? Ie load the first 2000 rows into table 1 and then 2001st row to 4000 rows on the next table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Issues when Loading Data with MySQL LOAD DATA INFILE

You appear to have a few issues going on here and to resolve you can make a few adjustments to get your data to load without error.

I've source referenced and quoted the items in more detail below so you can read up on each for a more thorough explanation.

**In short though essentially you can:**

1. Use the `LOCAL` keyword with the [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) statement to get the data to load with MySQL without needing to adjust the `my.ini` file parameters

   - `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '<file>'`
2. Use double backslashes [`\\`] in the folder path to separate folders rather than just one to escape the first backslash since by default a single backslash is used as a special escape character and ignored when used alone

   - `C:\\Users\\YCM LLC\\Desktop\\HFT\\ES_test.csv`
3. With the [`STR_TO_DATE`](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date.php) function for the second argument you pass it telling it the format for the time value in the first argument, you should use the `%h:%i:%s` or `%H:%i:%s` format

   - `time = STR_TO_DATE(@var2, '%h:%i:%s');`

---

### Further References

1. > The `LOCAL` keyword affects expected location of the file and error
   >   handling, as described later. `LOCAL` works only if your server and
   >   your client both have been configured to permit it. For example, if
   >   [**mysqld**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqld.html) was
   >   started with the **`local_infile`** system variable disabled, `LOCAL`
   >   does not work. See [Section 6.1.6, “Security Issues with LOAD DATA
   >   LOCAL”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data-local.html).
   >
   > The `LOCAL` keyword affects where the file is expected to be found:
   >
   > - If `LOCAL` is specified, the file is read by the client program on the client host and sent to the server. The file can be given as a
   >     full path name to specify its exact location. If given as a relative
   >     path name, the name is interpreted relative to the directory in which
   >     the client program was started.
   >
   >   When using `LOCAL` with **`LOAD DATA`**, a copy of the file is
   >     created in the server's temporary directory. This is not the directory
   >     determined by the value of **`tmpdir`** or **`slave_load_tmpdir`**,
   >     but rather the operating system's temporary directory, and is not
   >     configurable in the MySQL Server. (Typically the system temporary
   >     directory is `/tmp` on Linux systems and `C:\WINDOWS\TEMP` on
   >     Windows.) Lack of sufficient space for the copy in this directory can
   >     cause the **`LOAD DATA LOCAL`** statement to fail.
   >
   > <sub>[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html)</sub>

---

2. > Within a string, certain sequences have special meaning unless the
   >   **`NO_BACKSLASH_ESCAPES`** SQL mode is enabled. Each of these sequences begins with a backslash (`\`), known as the escape
   >   character. MySQL recognizes the escape sequences shown in [Table 9.1,
   >   “Special Character Escape
   >   Sequences”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html#character-escape-sequences).
   >   For all other escape sequences, backslash is ignored. That is, the
   >   escaped character is interpreted as if it was not escaped.
   >
   > > **Table 9.1 Special Character Escape Sequences**
   > >
   > > *Escape Sequence:* `\\`
   > >
   > > *Character Represented by Sequence:* A backslash (`\`) character
   >
   > <sub>[source](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-literals.html)</sub>

---

3. > **Description**
   >
   > The MySQL STR_TO_DATE function takes a string and returns a date
   >   specified by a format mask.
   >
   > **Syntax**
   >
   > The syntax for the STR_TO_DATE function in MySQL is:
   >
   > > `STR_TO_DATE( string, format_mask )`
   >
   > **Parameters or Arguments**
   >
   > ***string***
   >
   > The string value to format as a date.
   >
   > ***format_mask***
   >
   > The format to apply to string. The following is a list of options for
   >   the format_mask parameter. These parameters can be used in many
   >   combinations.
   >
   > [image]
   >
   > **Short List**
   >
   > > *Value:* `%H`
   > >
   > > *Description:* Hour (00 to 23)
   > >
   > > *Value:* `%h`
   > >
   > > *Description:* Hour (00 to 12)
   > >
   > > *Value:* `%i`
   > >
   > > *Description:* Minutes (00 to 59)
   > >
   > > *Value:* `%s`
   > >
   > > *Description:* Seconds (00 to 59)
   >
   > <sub>[source](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/str_to_date.php)</sub>